# window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); is undefined in my application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, blob

I'm facing this issue only in my application irrespective of browser (IE & Chrome). If I check `window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)` in console of any other page in both the browsers, its working fine. But it `window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)` is getting undefined only in the tab in which I open my application :(

I'm not sure, which library is removing "createObjectURL" method.

following are my scripts

```
<script src="src/js/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="src/js/libs/toastr/toastr.js"></script>
<script src="src/js/libs/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="src/js/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="src/js/libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="src/js/libs/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="src/js/libs/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js></script>
<script src="src/js/libs/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="src/js/libs/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<script src="src/js/libs/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

I'm not able to figure out how to get `window.URL.createObjectURL`

Here is the error in IE console

> Error: [IGL] Object doesn't support property or method 'createObjectURL'
>   TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'createObjectURL'

Here is the error in Chrome

> Error: [IGL] window.URL.createObjectURL is not a function
>   TypeError: window.URL.createObjectURL is not a function

Thanks in advance

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: How to make it avaliable?

Comment: What is the **exact** error message and where are you seeing it? In the browser console?

Comment: @ShivKumar check which script has removed it.

Comment: Yes @zerkms, I'm trying to figure out that.. but no luck...

Comment: What version of IE (it's only available in 10+)? What is the error in Chrome?

Comment: @Phil IE11 & Version 42.0.2311.90 m

Comment: and again... **what is the error in Chrome**?

Comment: @Phil, in chrome, I could able to get it with window.webkitURL. I'm actually using as follows

(window.webkitURL ? window.webkitURL : window.URL).createObjectURL(blob);

Comment: `window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;`

Comment: @Phil Updated both the errors in question. I could able to get window.URL.createObjectURL in other tabs. But not in my application.

Comment: @Kaiido that's not going to work very well in non-webkit browsers that also do not support `URL`

Comment: @Phil why it won't? either window.URL is defined and it will be picked, or window.webkitURL is defined then it will pick that one.

Comment: @Kaiido because, window.URL will not be undefined or null. so everytime it takes window.URL

Comment: ok then `window.myURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;` before any script has loaded

Comment: I'd say there's a very strong chance some script (though maybe not any of the above) is setting `var URL = something` in the global scope. I would search all your code for `URL` (case sensitive)

Comment: @Phil you are right. Just now I figure out it with Arun's answer, but someone has deleted it.

Comment: And that kids, is why you don't set variables in the global scope if you can help it

Comment: Yes @Phil you are absolutly right. I have actually moved all the global variables to constants in angular module, but I missed this one. Thanks again for very quick help

Answer (score 8):

I figure out the solution for this by using following script from Arun & @Phil comments. Thanks to both of them.

Its not with any library, in my application somewhere in unused code, there a global URL object which is overriding the window.URL.

I found this by using the following code:

```
(function () {
        var _createObjectURL = window.URL.createObjectURL;
                Object.defineProperty(window.URL, 'createObjectURL', {
                set: function (value) {
                console.trace('set createObjectURL')
                        _createObjectURL = value;
                },
                        get: function () {
                        console.trace('get createObjectURL')
                                return _createObjectURL;
                        }
                })
                })();
                (function () {
                var _URL = window.URL;
                        Object.defineProperty(window, 'URL', {
                        set: function (value) {
                        console.trace('set URL')
                                _URL = value;
                        },
                                get: function () {
                                console.trace('get URL')
                                        return _URL;
                                }
                        })
                        })();
```

Comment: KUDOS for a pointer! One of my colleagues was unintentionally overwriting window.URL with his url munching utility with custom methods and such.

I didn't use your code snippet, just used project-wise search for "URL" assignments and manually went through them till I found.