# JSpdf working in Internet Explorer but not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, django, jspdf, filesaver.js

Hi I am a bit stuck here, trying to use jspdf for printing html to pdf. So first of all I tried with some examples and it worked. But when I try to implement the same in My Django Website, there is an issue.

**1. Its working with Internet explorer, I am able to download the Pdf**

**2. But same is not working with Chrome (why).**

By following some post :[get_URL().createObjectURL error](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/143)  I was able understand that:

> issue is with the AJax Calls where i am changing the URL to some other
>   value.

Also looked in to  :[window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); is undefined in my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787028/window-url-createobjecturlblob-is-undefined-in-my-application)

But it doesn't says any clear solution to the problem. How to make the things work.

> So far I have checked : None of the JS files inclusion is missed , as
>   its working fine with internet explorer. But in Explorer my ajax Calls doesn't works

Here is the error I am getting [image]

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: As the answers you have linked say, you have almost certainly got some code that says var URL = something.  Have you checked all your code and any 3rd party code you use for URL (case sensitively)?

Comment: Ya I do , I am using some Ajax calls their i have set some URL, But the question how to solve it , having still used the URL , and absolutely no idea why it works in Internet explorer .but not in Chrome

Comment: And have you tried renaming them as per the advice in the articles you already found?

Comment: have you tried using window.webkitURL.createObjectURL() ? Also are you serving your page via some local server or just opening plain html?

Comment: Still this question is unanswered . Hope if someone could answer it

Comment: Isn't one of your plugins blocking a cetain javascript file? I had that some times

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I can help much, but what I understand is that the error you are seeing is caused by createObjectURL being undefined, so the first thing I would check is why this happens.

Have you tried writing something like `window.ULR.createObjectURL(new Blob)` in the console? Try writing this on your application page, and if it stil happens, you have something that changes the URL object.

The next step would be to temporarily remove one javascript file at a time to find out which one makes the trouble.

Note: Yes, I know the question is old, but it still deserves a solution.